# Is my computer the reason for a strange render screen?

Tags: rendering

I *think* this is just my pc.. but I wanna make sure[image: weirdblenderthing]

Comment: Did you accidentally have a duplicated plane inside your scene? We need more description to figure out what is the real problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 2 planes overlapping each other. Take a look at the outliner panel and check if there are duplicate plane objects in your scene.

If you can't see the duplicate plane in the 3D viewport, but it shows up in render - It's very likely that you have either hidden (the eye icon in the outliner) or disabled (the monitor icon) it in your viewport. Click on the filter button and enable the toggles if you can't find them.

[image: outliner] [image: toggle filters]